# Think different or what should I do with issues after migration to Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode6

I am using Xcode 6 and it's pretty good, but I have about ten reposes with sources that were written using Xcode 5. So on Xcode 5 it is works perfect. I have never pushed pods libraries to my reposes. I just have Podfile and after I pull or clone some of my projects I just make pod install and everything works perfect.

So I just faced with issue that cause many warnings and errors using Xcode 6. So I was following the same way as for Xcode 5:

1. I've clon project.
2. pod install
3. Run project from created workspace

and here we are Xcode 6 says you have a lot of issues (while Xcode 5 says nothing)

So it's about 40 issues that say the same:

```
Apple Mach-O Linker Error
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "_CGPDFDocumentCreateX", referenced from:
```

and 39 other for other files.

What should I do to fix this issues? Seems I every time should think different after Apple release new software version.

Comment: You're missing a framework and if the Xcode 5 project linked with that framework, opening it in Xcode 6 should also work.

Comment: should ) but in does not =) as I said the Xcode 5 build the same project without any problem, but the same project on Xcode 6 cloned form repo cause many issues. For current time it is seems architecture issues

Comment: Nope; it's just project settings, and every project I've tried, that worked with Xcode 5, also worked with Xcode 6 without modification.

Comment: Are you using any Third party library ? "CGPDFDocumentCreateX"

Comment: yes I am using vfr reader as for this issues

Comment: Yeah, I had almost the same problem, when I started using Xcode6, but with another framework. What I did for resolve this problem is just add '#import "framework that contains CGPDFDocumentCreateX"', for my case it was OpenGLES framework